# The array does not output properly

Tags: csv, d3.js

```
let test = [];

d3.csv("cgvList.csv", function (data) { 
    if (data.poi_nm == "CGV") { 
      let obj = {};
      obj.content = '<div>' + data.branch_nm + '</div>';

      test.push(obj); 
    }
});
console.log(test);
console.log("test[0] : " + test[0]);
console.log("test.length : " + test.length);
[enter image description here][1]
```

I made the csv file into an object array.

And as a result of outputting the array, the array was output well,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPMOH.png)
but when outputting index 0, undefined came out and the length of the array was also 0.
It was printed properly when it was printed from the console.

What's the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViQLA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a jsfiddle or sandbox to play with, I can't tell exactly what is going on, but what I believe is happening is a mix of two things:

1. `d3.csv` is an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), and therefore returns a promise.
2. The function you pass on to `d3.csv` is supposed to tell the function how to parse every element in the csv, and should return the parsed object, not add it to an external array or anything like that. Every element you return in that function will be an element in your resulting array

There's (at least) two possible ways you can deal with this:

1. `await` the async function, and its return value will be your required value, something like

```js
const test = await d3.csv("cgvList.csv", function (data) { 
    if (data.poi_nm == "CGV") { 
      let obj = {};
      obj.content = '<div>' + data.branch_nm + '</div>';

      return obj; 
    }
});
console.log(test);
console.log("test[0] : " + test[0]);
console.log("test.length : " + test.length);
```

Notice that here the function you pass onto `d3.csv` returns the object in the way you want to format it!

2. Do your logic in a `.then` statement, which also waits for the promise to be fulfilled:

```js
d3.csv("cgvList.csv", function (data) { 
    if (data.poi_nm == "CGV") { 
      let obj = {};
      obj.content = '<div>' + data.branch_nm + '</div>';

      return obj; 
    }
}).then((test) => {
   console.log(test);
   console.log("test[0] : " + test[0]);
   console.log("test.length : " + test.length);
});
```